# Runing multiple videos together in iOS.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, video

I would like to play multiple videos in my iPhone app.

I did try using myVideoPlayer library,  but when I do so, I only be able to run four of them together.The rest don't response.

I need the final result to be like this:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18654072/MadPad.mov

do you have any suggestion?

Thanks